# How do I determine which version of Alpine this Elixir image uses?

Tags: docker, elixir

I'm running through the distillery guide with Docker for the first time. It says here:

```
# This should match the version of Alpine that the `elixir:1.7.2-alpine` image uses
ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.8

FROM elixir:1.7.2-alpine AS builder
```

How do I determine which version of Alpine elixir:1.7.2-alpine uses? [How can I tell on this page](https://hub.docker.com/_/elixir)? (Can you?) If I get a version mismatch, it throws this error:

```
Unusable Erlang runtime system! This is likely due to being compiled for another system than the host is running
```

Trying this for Elixir 1.13.4 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the [hexpm images](https://hub.docker.com/r/hexpm/elixir), which unlike the "official" images list in the tag name the precise OS, Erlang, and Elixir versions used, and do not retroactively update the same tags underlying OS/Erlang versions.

There is an [open PR](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/pull/2206) to add this advice to the readme for the official docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Click [TAGS](https://hub.docker.com/_/elixir/tags), you can find the different versions, and [This one are you looking for](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/elixir/1.7.2-alpine/images/sha256-97d4954089b03d19b4c60d8324827b683f64e9526d4b3514050b468c9905d8b0?context=explore)

Comment: This is the Elixir version, not the Alpine version? How can I find the 3.8 on this page that's mentioned in`ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.8`?

Comment: Sorry for dumb questions! Just not sure where I can get that specific version that's compatible with the version of Elixir I'm running in the container